# How can I unlock drive without the password or recovery key of Bitlocker?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker

Is it possible to unlock my drive without the password or recovery key of Bitlocker? If so, how? I tried Elcomsoft forensic software but I'm not able to decrypt it without using the password or recovery key.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: You can't

Bitlocker uses AES-XTS 128 or AES-XTS 256.
As long as the drive is not mounted and unlocked (whereas you could just disable bitlocker or export the password/recovery key) there is no way of bypassung this.